# Python NameError (Django)

Tags: python, django, nameerror

This is code in models.py

```
class Package(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
  version=models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
  home_page=models.URLField(blank=True)
  summary=models.TextField()
  description=models.TextField(blank=True)
  keywords=models.TextField(blank=True)
  categories=models.ManyToManyField(Category,related_name='packages')



class Category(models.Model):
  topic=models.ForeignKey(Package, related_name="categories")
```

When i try to syncdb it says "NameError Category is not defined" i tried placing class category first and package next this time it says "NameError name Package is not defined".

Please help me out of this problem.

EDIT: 
Thanks for the help guys, from a very little knowledge of what i know in databases the tutorial here seems wrong http://toys.jacobian.org/presentations/2007/pycon/tutorials/beginning/ 
He has defined the field categories in Packages to be many-to-many and the field in Category topic to be a foreign key to Package ,but a foreign key is a many-to-one relationship, therefore the implementation is flawed. 
I think django is trying to tell it in its way as "Accessor for field 'topic' clashes with m2m field 'Package.categories'." Reverse query name for field 'topic' clashes with m2m field ' "
Is that correct?

Comment: That just seems like a typo: the ForeignKey should be pointing at the Topic model, not the Package, that's why it's called `topic`. But why are you looking at a five-year-old slideshow? Plenty of things in it are out of date.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you please give links to some good tutorials. I've tried here [link]https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials[link] most of the tutorials looked obscure and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

["If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself..."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships)

```
class Package(models.Model):
   ...
  categories=models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='packages')
```

Comment: Thanks it works when the related_name argument is not used.
but got this error when using the related_name
`Error: One or more models did not validate:packages.category: Accessor for field 'topic' clashes with m2m field 'Package.categories'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'topic'.
packages.category: Reverse query name for field 'topic' clashes with m2m field '
Package.categories'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'topic'. `
I don't exactly understand what it says. How do i get past it.

Comment: You need to give one of the relational fields a different `related_name`, or make one of them unidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes while you define `category` `ManyToManyField`.
Change to:

```
categories=models.ManyToManyField('Category',related_name='packages')
```

Reason: `Category` is not defined while you add that field, so need to add quotes around it so that django will resolve it later.

Comment: I'm a django newbie i did what you said.these are the exact changes
`class Category(models.Model):
    topic=models.ForeignKey('Package', related_name='categories')`

and this in the class Package
`
categories=models.ManyToManyField('Category',related_name='packages') `

Comment: And this is the error
` Error: One or more models did not validate:
packages.category: Accessor for field 'topic' clashes with m2m field 'Package.categories'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'topic'.packages.category: Reverse query name for field 'topic' clashes with m2m field '
Package.categories'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'topic'.`

I don't understand a thing, i am newbie to django

Comment: You can change `topic=models.ForeignKey('Package', related_name='topics')`. With your code when its trying to set reverse relationship the names are clashing.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna You may want to readup at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name